# Floating Javascript button

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically creating a button object. I need it float right is there a property of the object that i could set to do this?

```
var LogOutButton = {
                background: {},
                borders: {},
                id: -1,
                label: "Log off",
                labelColor: "rgb(64,64,64)",
                labelFont: { textDecoration: "underline" },                    
                parentId: 286,
                rect: { height: 15, right: 10, top: 5, width: 50},
                screenId: 286,
                style: "Button",
            };
```

Comment: The jackson tag doesn't seem related. Is XML or JSON involved at all here? You need to clarify, in the body of the question, what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: I want to create a button using javascript alone that will align itself to the right side of the screen and will stay there as the screen is adjusted. (the width is made larger and smaller by the user)

Comment: Are you using some sort of UI or presentation API? AFAIK, a button is just a DOM thing that you style and position using techniques that alter the DOM (like CSS and HTML, or whatever presentation manipulation layer you have).